# How a Web Application works?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, netbeans, web-applications

I am new to this web application thing and I have just started creating a `web application` using *JSP* for my implant training but I am very much tangled with these questions in my head.

1. Do the computers in the client side need java installed for utilizing my web application because I am using JSP ?
2. How will the computers access my web application after I host it in the server?
3. What is the procedure to host the application in the server.

I am developing my web application in Netbeans IDE and the server is Tomcat  but everything is in my personal computer, very soon I will have to deploy it in actual server and how should I make my web application a stand alone application ( To work without NetBeans IDE ).

Comment: I know java better than other programming languages which I know. That's the reason I choose JSP but can you tell me how these web application works or the architecture of it?

Comment: java on desktop is a thing, java on web is totally a different thing :)

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow which focuses on a narrow specific nitty-gritty programming problem. I suggest you suspend your programming attempts briefly to learn more about the general architecture of Java Servlets, .war files, and containers such as Tomcat or Jetty. Start with Wikipedia, then Oracle site for tutorials and guides, and perhaps [this O’Reilly book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/mobile/9780596516680.do) (book is outdated but good at teaching the basics). Bonus tip: [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, client only need a web browser.
2. Client can call your server IP address (`http://192.168.1.10/app`) or call its domain if you have setup your domain (`http://yourdomain.com/app`)
3. You can run your application on any computer (Linux, Windows, Mac, Solaris, BSD, etc.) capable of running Java SE (Standard Edition). Tomcat runs on top of Java SE.